# Cant get data from access data base

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

I'm new in c#, and when I try to connect access db, I get an empty db, and empty tables, although they have data.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String connectioString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Documents\Documents\School.accdb";
    OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(connectioString);
    MyConn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader reader = null;
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Students",MyConn);
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    Console.Out.WriteLine(reader["Id_fk"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation for the `OleDbDataReader.Read()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read?#remarks):

> The default position of the [OleDbDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader) is before the first
>   record. Therefore, you must call [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.read) to start accessing any data.

Therefore, you need to access the properties of the result row(s) like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
    Console.Out.WriteLine(reader["Id_fk"].ToString());
```